# Spark - Check status of application programmatically

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark Cluster running in client mode. I programmatically submit jobs to spark cluster. Under the hood, I am using spark-submit.

If my cluster is overloaded and I start a context, the driver JVM keeps on waiting for executors. The executors are in waiting state because cluster does not have enough resources. Here are the log messages in driver logs

```
2017-10-27 13:20:15,260 WARN Timer-0 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl []: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2017-10-27 13:20:30,259 WARN Timer-0 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl []: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Is it possible to programmatically check the status of application (e.g. Running/Waiting etc)? I know that we can use the application id and then query the history server but I would like to know a solution which does not involve REST calls to history server.

SparkContext should know about the state? How can i get this information from sc?

Comment: I have not found what you are exactly looking for in `SparkListener`, but I think it provides access to some Spark's internal events which might be useful to you?

Comment: Thanks. I checked most of the events but the event which is useful for me is probably ApplicationStart but I haven't been able to get it running. Any idea?